# Coldfusion 8 and JQuery Toggle

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, toggle

I'm trying to implement the Toggle function in Jquery for the first. When I tested it out in a simple html page, it worked. Than I copied the code into my CF page. Since I'm trying to have it pulled from my database dynamically, it implemented the function on all the `<p>` tag. I think I have to use the `this` command somewhere but not sure how to used it properly to make it work. When the user click on the biography they want, it will open up only 1 instead of all the other biography at the same time. Suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle_container")
    });

});
</script>


<cfif Statement NEQ ''>
<p><a class="trigger" href="##">Research Profile</a></p>
<p class="toggle_container">#Statement#</p>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two different jquery implementations here.

This line uses jquery hide to hide the element:

```
$(".toggle_container").hide();
```

This uses jquery toggleClass line to toggle a class:

```
$(this).toggleClass("toggle_container")
```

The class is not specified in your code so it has no class to toggle. [jquery toggleClass docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

You could try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".toggle_container").hide();

$('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
});
});
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/bgWJz/

Comment: Thanks you it works! Question - could you explain click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

Comment: It will prevent the link from jumping to the top of the document; it's 'default' behavior in this case.

Comment: Glad to help. You'll see that preventDefault used in many other instances. Please accept my answer. Thanks.